# Debian Jessie samba start on boot

Tags: samba, boot, debian-jessie

I'm having issues starting samba on boot on Debian Jessie. I do not understand how to do it as it seems that the `samba` script wrapper is deliberately made not to work.

I tried to issue a `update-rc.d samba defaults` but it will not modify the system configuration to start at boot.

Comment: The service will not start at boot even after issuing the update-rc.d command. It seems it is not doing anything

Comment: Jessie uses systemd. What about `systemctl enable samba`?

Comment: update-rc.d: error: samba Default-Start contains no runlevels, aborting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the following command to enable `samba`:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable smbd.service nmbd.service
Synchronizing state for smbd.service with sysvinit using update-rc.d...
Executing /usr/sbin/update-rc.d smbd defaults
Executing /usr/sbin/update-rc.d smbd enable
Synchronizing state for nmbd.service with sysvinit using update-rc.d...
Executing /usr/sbin/update-rc.d nmbd defaults
Executing /usr/sbin/update-rc.d nmbd enable
$
```

and to check:

```
$ sudo systemctl status smbd
● smbd.service - LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/smbd)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2016-02-22 18:56:27 JST; 12min ago
   CGroup: /system.slice/smbd.service
           ├─3756 /usr/sbin/smbd -D
           └─3771 /usr/sbin/smbd -D

Feb 22 18:56:27 debian smbd[3747]: Starting SMB/CIFS daemon: smbd.
Feb 22 19:03:13 debian smbd[4042]: Reloading /etc/samba/smb.conf: smbd.
$
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me; I get `active (exited)` for both daemons and `connection refused` when I try `smbclient -L localhost -U%`.  Any thoughts? This is driving me mad.